# How to use function in route at laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I need to use function inside route to return controller name. This is my router code.

```php
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'],function(){
    Route::Resource('profile', return_controller(session()->get('category')));
});

function return_controller($category_id) {
    switch ($category_id) {
        case 1: return 'ServicesHallController';
            break;
        case 2: return 'ServicesBeautycenterController';
            break;
        case 3: return 'ServicesDressController';
            break;
        case 4: return 'ServicesCarController';
            break;
        case 5: return 'ServicesPhotographyController';
            break;
        case 6: return 'ServicesHoneymoonController';
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of this, use middleware which would send the request to specific controller or a controller for routing the request

Comment: are you sure `session()->get('category')` will return the `category_id` and not just the `category`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a middleware to process your check.
Refact your controller_returns function into a middleware.

Otherwise, laravel is PHP, so if you call a function where a string is needed and that function returns a string that should work.
 If **it does not** you might have forgotten the namespace in your returned string.

**exemple**: 'name\space\controllerName'

And if it's still doesn't work check if your session storage is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the controller names into a lookup array, and access it as an inline string like so:

```
$controllers = [
    1 => 'ServicesHallController',
    2 => 'ServicesBeautycenterController',
    3 => 'ServicesDressController',
    4 => 'ServicesCarController',
    5 => 'ServicesPhotographyController',
    6 => 'ServicesHoneymoonController',
];

Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'],function(){
    Route::Resource('profile', $controllers[session()->get('category')]);
});
```

If you wanted, you could put the controllers lookup table into a config array. An array is a little more portable and easier to maintain than a select structure.